# How can I show the table structure in SQL Server query?

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT DateTime, Skill, Name, TimeZone, ID, User, Employee, Leader 
FROM t_Agent_Skill_Group_Half_Hour AS t
```

I need to view the table structure in a query.

Comment: What do you mean as a _table structure_? Your question isn't clear IMO.

Comment: i mean as example the column name skill .... the query must return skill .. DBINT:int

Comment: We call that "table schema".

Comment: SQL Server is the worst thing I have seen

Comment: The terminal output is horrendous!  this is something mysql team got right.  Microsoft suck at command line interfaces.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

For SQL Server, if using a newer version, you can use

```
select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME='tableName'
```

There are different ways to get the schema. Using ADO.NET, you can use the [schema methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcax58fh.aspx). Use the `DbConnection`'s [`GetSchema` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s98te64s.aspx) or the `DataReader`'s[`GetSchemaTable` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.getschematable.aspx).

Provided that you have a reader for the for the query, you can do something like this:

```
using(DbCommand cmd = ...)
using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    var schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
    foreach(DataRow row in schema.Rows)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(row["ColumnName"] + " - " + row["DataTypeName"])
    }
}
```

See [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310107) for further details.

Comment: i need a query to test in Microsoft SQL Management Studio :s

Comment: @BassamQarib - why do you tag the question C# if you need to do it in Management Studio?

Comment: To access a table defined in a particular database, you may need to have "use <database name>" at the beginning, especially, when you execute without specifying the connected database.

Answer (score 67):

`sp_help tablename` in sql server

`desc tablename` in oracle

Comment: So, what exactly is the difference between "sp_help tablename" and '''
select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME='tableName' 
'''

Comment: @ArchanJoshi: Try it, execute one and the other and you'll see. "sp_help" gives you information on PK's, constraints, while the other provides more information on the columns themselves

Comment: syntax for a table in another schema  sp_help 'schema.tablename'  eg sp_help 'geo.test'

Answer (score 22):

**Try this query:**

```
DECLARE @table_name SYSNAME
SELECT @table_name = 'dbo.test_table'

DECLARE 
      @object_name SYSNAME
    , @object_id INT

SELECT 
      @object_name = '[' + s.name + '].[' + o.name + ']'
    , @object_id = o.[object_id]
FROM sys.objects o WITH (NOWAIT)
JOIN sys.schemas s WITH (NOWAIT) ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE s.name + '.' + o.name = @table_name
    AND o.[type] = 'U'
    AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

;WITH index_column AS 
(
    SELECT 
          ic.[object_id]
        , ic.index_id
        , ic.is_descending_key
        , ic.is_included_column
        , c.name
    FROM sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON ic.[object_id] = c.[object_id] AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
    WHERE ic.[object_id] = @object_id
)
SELECT @SQL = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @object_name + CHAR(13) + '(' + CHAR(13) + STUFF((
    SELECT CHAR(9) + ', [' + c.name + '] ' + 
        CASE WHEN c.is_computed = 1
            THEN 'AS ' + cc.[definition] 
            ELSE UPPER(tp.name) + 
                CASE WHEN tp.name IN ('varchar', 'char', 'varbinary', 'binary', 'text')
                       THEN '(' + CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN 'MAX' ELSE CAST(c.max_length AS VARCHAR(5)) END + ')'
                     WHEN tp.name IN ('nvarchar', 'nchar', 'ntext')
                       THEN '(' + CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN 'MAX' ELSE CAST(c.max_length / 2 AS VARCHAR(5)) END + ')'
                     WHEN tp.name IN ('datetime2', 'time2', 'datetimeoffset') 
                       THEN '(' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(5)) + ')'
                     WHEN tp.name = 'decimal' 
                       THEN '(' + CAST(c.[precision] AS VARCHAR(5)) + ',' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(5)) + ')'
                    ELSE ''
                END +
                CASE WHEN c.collation_name IS NOT NULL THEN ' COLLATE ' + c.collation_name ELSE '' END +
                CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 1 THEN ' NULL' ELSE ' NOT NULL' END +
                CASE WHEN dc.[definition] IS NOT NULL THEN ' DEFAULT' + dc.[definition] ELSE '' END + 
                CASE WHEN ic.is_identity = 1 THEN ' IDENTITY(' + CAST(ISNULL(ic.seed_value, '0') AS CHAR(1)) + ',' + CAST(ISNULL(ic.increment_value, '1') AS CHAR(1)) + ')' ELSE '' END 
        END + CHAR(13)
    FROM sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN sys.types tp WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.user_type_id = tp.user_type_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.computed_columns cc WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = cc.[object_id] AND c.column_id = cc.column_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.default_constraints dc WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.default_object_id != 0 AND c.[object_id] = dc.parent_object_id AND c.column_id = dc.parent_column_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.identity_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.is_identity = 1 AND c.[object_id] = ic.[object_id] AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
    WHERE c.[object_id] = @object_id
    ORDER BY c.column_id
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, CHAR(9) + ' ')
    + ISNULL((SELECT CHAR(9) + ', CONSTRAINT [' + k.name + '] PRIMARY KEY (' + 
                    (SELECT STUFF((
                         SELECT ', [' + c.name + '] ' + CASE WHEN ic.is_descending_key = 1 THEN 'DESC' ELSE 'ASC' END
                         FROM sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT)
                         JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = ic.[object_id] AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
                         WHERE ic.is_included_column = 0
                             AND ic.[object_id] = k.parent_object_id 
                             AND ic.index_id = k.unique_index_id     
                         FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, ''))
            + ')' + CHAR(13)
            FROM sys.key_constraints k WITH (NOWAIT)
            WHERE k.parent_object_id = @object_id 
                AND k.[type] = 'PK'), '') + ')'  + CHAR(13)

PRINT @SQL
```

**Output:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test_table]
(
      [WorkOutID] BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
    , [DateOut] DATETIME NOT NULL
    , [EmployeeID] INT NOT NULL
    , [IsMainWorkPlace] BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT((1))
    , [WorkPlaceUID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL
    , [WorkShiftCD] NVARCHAR(10) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL
    , [CategoryID] INT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT [PK_WorkOut] PRIMARY KEY ([WorkOutID] ASC)
)
```

**Also read this:**

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/67b45a/how-to-generate-a-create-table-script-for-an-existing-table/

Comment: In SSMS right-click table, select **Script Table as > Create To > New Query Editor Window**.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I don't have Sql Server Management Studio. All I have is the Azure Sql Query Editor.

Comment: To use this to get a creation table script from a view just change the code at line 14 `AND o.[type] = 'U'` for this `AND o.[type] in ('U', 'V')`

Comment: @Devart, you're a good man, sir

Comment: would be great to get similar solution compatible on azure synapse dedicated sql pool

Answer (score 19):

On SQL Server 2012, you can use the following stored procedure:

```
sp_columns '<table name>'
```

For example, given a database table named users:

```
sp_columns 'users'
```

Comment: this worked for me

Answer (score 6):

**In SQL Server, you can use this query:**

```
USE Database_name

SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='Table_Name';
```

And do not forget to replace `Database_name` and `Table_name` with the exact names of your database and table names.

Answer (score 3):

For recent versions of SQL Server Management Studio Write the  in a query editor and Do "Alt" + "F1"

Comment: I remembered this feature has been available since SQL 2005.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select *
from (SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_NAME='brands')[.brands];
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -1):

I was trying 'DESC table_name' but then this worked for me in psql:

```
select * 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME='table_name';
```

Comment: How does this differ from the already accepted answer?

Answer (score -2):

To print a schema, I use jade and do an export to a file of the database then bring it into word to format and print

Comment: Please consider explaining your answer.