# How to get Object Schema using TSQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012-express

Aside from *sp_help 'mytablename'* which gives a break of each element of an object, is there a way getting the raw SQL. Just the same as doing the following in Microsoft SQL Server.

[image: Microsoft SQL Server - Script Table]

Using *sp_helptext 'mytablename'* says the following;

> There is no text for object 'Track'.

Update: sp_helptext works for a stored procedure but not for a table;

[image: sp_help on a Stored Procedure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [sp_helptext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms176112.aspx) stored procedure to get the same; like

```
sp_helptext tablename
```

This will return you the SQL `CREATE TABLE` text for the specific table (or whichever object you specify; could be stored procedure\function\etc ).

Per your edited post where you say `There is no text for object 'Track'`. I am not sure but check whether you have permission to see object body (OR) it's not encrypted with `WITH ENCRYPTION` option.

you can as well use [OBJECT_DEFINITION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176090.aspx) like `OBJECT_DEFINITION ( object_id )`.

```
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION (OBJECT_ID(N'Person.uAddress'))
```

Only difference is, it won't get you the source code for a Table (all objects other than table)

**EDIT:**

You can script a table using SSMS (same way you have pictured in your post). Not sure why that's not serving your purpose.

You can as well use `sp_help`.

If you are looking for something like `DESCRIBE` in Oracle (OR) `SHOW TABLE` in MySQL then there is no such built-in mechanism available but you can combine all the data in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`/`sys.objects`/etc and create a custom script to achieve the same. Found the below post where people have already documented the same kind of script. You can use the same. Take a look.

[How can I show the table structure in SQL Server query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298433/how-can-i-show-the-table-structure-in-sql-server-query)

[In SQL Server, how do I generate a CREATE TABLE statement for a given table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547/in-sql-server-how-do-i-generate-a-create-table-statement-for-a-given-table)

Comment: Sorry this returns nothing