# Connect to a single SQL Server database with dbConnect in R

Tags: r, sql-server, dbi

I'm new to connecting to databases hosted in SQL Server.

The following code works:

```
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string = "Driver={SQL Server};", 
                 user = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Your computer usename e.g. SmithJo"), 
                 password = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Your computer password (e.g. to login to Windows)"), 
                 port = 1433, 
                server = "myserver", 
                dbname = "ABC")
```

However, the connections pane then shows a number of databases:
[image]

When I use the command `dbListTables(con)`, are the tables listed JUST from database ABC?

Comment: SQL Server returns a LOT of crap^Htables and views and meta-things and such when you list the tables. I wish I knew how to programmatically cut out the system objects. An approximation might be to use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18298685/3358272) (or related), as I find its output is tables (and columns) only.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this so if you had any idea on how to translate that to R...?

Comment: @r2evans ... if you think SQL Server is bad, try Oracle! I use `options(connectionObserver = NULL)` at top of script to avoid those other items.

Comment: No thanks, I'm having enough trouble dealing with MS's implementation of ODBC ... their own protocol, nonetheless, which [requires the user to know the underlying storage of some columns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/getting-long-data?view=sql-server-2017). The fact that [`nanodbc`](http://github.com/nanodbc/nanodbc/) and [`odbc`](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc) punt on this flaw makes my deailng with sqlserver in one thread and postgres in another to be ... a nightmare. (RIP, [`RSQLServer`](https://github.com/imanuelcostigan/RSQLServer), you are missed.)

Comment: @Nova ... err, `DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS")`? Or if you need just table names (as you would get with `dbListTables`), then `DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select table_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS")`

Comment: Now we are getting somewhere... that is helpful. Still having trouble connecting to the lookup tables though...

Comment: Re-reading your post, what is your question? Connect across databases? Across schemas? *are the tables listed JUST from database ABC?* ... aren't you able to answer that question?

Comment: Thanks Parfait, you're right - I should just ask one question per post. I've edited my post. I'm still not sure that the tables listed are from just the ABC table, it seems like yes? r2evans helped me access the "meaningful" tables with their comment, though.

Comment: The new question is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52209203/dbreadtable-error-in-r-invalid-object-name. @r2evans... any ideas?

Comment: To address *this* question, I believe `dbListTables(con)` is specific to the database connection provided (`con`); other databases, other schemas, etc, need to be queried specifically, I believe. (Caveat: I'm really only familiar with changing specific databases on the same server or changing servers completely, not much about other terminology/structures, clustered dbs, etc.)

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to make sure I was getting the right information. That's... that's a lot of tables.