# How to get the schema from a datatable?

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, sqlconnection

I have a datatable. I need to get and return the schema of the datatable below.

How can I get the schema?

```
using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
{
    var result = reader.AsDataSet();
    DataTable firstTable = result.Tables[0];
    var schema = ???
}
```

Comment: What are you calling `schema`? The database structure or the schema name, like "dbo"?

Comment: If you mean the structure, data types, etc.,  [check this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlDataReader_GetSchemaTable)

Comment: the structure of the table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I show the table structure in SQL Server query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298433/how-can-i-show-the-table-structure-in-sql-server-query)